# STM32F769I-DISCO - Really noisy TFT LCD display

Tags: stm32, lcd, tft

I am a new user of an STM32F769I-DISCO MCU and the problem I'm having is with one of the examples called "BSP".

I'm using the STM32CubeIDE to build and run the files. The program does build and run successfully. However, the TFT LCD display looks horrible: it looks like one of those old CRT TV noisy channels (picture below).

The part that produces this noise is the function `BSP_LCD_Init()` in the 100th row of the main.c file, which can be found [here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF7/blob/master/Projects/STM32F769I-Discovery/Examples/BSP/Src/main.c).

The funny thing is that this is an example that comes with the IDE, but it doesn't work for some reason. I already tried this with my laptop and my PC and it comes up with the same result. The whole example can be found [here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF7/tree/master/Projects/STM32F769I-Discovery/Examples/BSP).

[image: Noisy display]

Comment: I'm not going to look through a whole github project to see what you did. Did you set the pixels to anything? e.g. set all of them to blue?

Comment: Looks more like some timing error. Connect your oscilloscope or logic analyzer and find out what's going on.

Comment: Looks like it's just displaying whatever random data is in the block of memory your project uses for the framebuffer. You need to write some sort of image data there for the display to show anything other than what you see now (or at least zero the whole block for a blank display).

Comment: If there's a transmission problem the static will change all the time. If it stays the same picture then probably you just didn't set up a picture to display. Which one is it?

Comment: Does your code get past the `while(lcd_status != LCD_OK);` on line 101? It's only clearing the buffer after that on line 105.

Comment: It's the same static picture and yes, all of the pixels are written in the example to display something specific.

Comment: The code does get past line 101 and actually into the next while-loop, where it should be displaying the different demos.

Comment: Check that `LCD_FB_START_ADDRESS` has been correctly defined to point to a valid RAM memory address. That value is the location in memory which is supposed to be used as the framebuffer for the display.

Comment: For anyone passing by, the solution is detailed here https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00002GZV1xSAH/stm32f769idisco-really-noisy-tft-lcd-display